# Point Gandi SUBdomain DNS to a netlify app without impacting the main domain

Tags: dns, subdomain, netlify

A have a gandi account with a domain which must run 3 applications

- mydomain.com is a simple WordPress commercial website (it uses the actual Gandi DNS)
- manager.mydomain.com is a backend application (it uses the actual Gandi DNS)
- app.mydomain.com is a front application on netlify that SHOULD use Netlify DNS

I need to know the steps to reproduce in Gandi to make app.mydomain.com use Netlify's DNS instead of gandi's, and without breaking the 2 other apps

I have tried some stuffs but i only managed to break the 2 first apps

I someone can help ! Thanks !!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK actually it's possible do delegate the management of the DNS zone of a SUBDOMAIN by creating NS recording inside the DNS zone of the main domain

Inside Gandi for example go to "advanced view" / "Edit the Zone file" and copy paste your Netlify dns here for example:

- app 10800 IN NS dns4.p07.nsone.net
- app 10800 IN NS dns3.p07.nsone.net
- app 10800 IN NS dns1.p07.nsone.net
- app 10800 IN NS dns2.p07.nsone.net

Hope this will help noobs like me !